# Trying to start Chrome from WSGI/Python (admittedly quick-and-dirty) [Win. XP, x86, Python 2.7, Apache 2.2]

Tags: python, apache, google-chrome, mod-wsgi, wsgi

So typically I am too stubborn to use forum sites myself (call me proud), but this has been driving me absolutely mad.

My goal is simply **to start Chrome on a server machine, through that server's python WSGI script**. I am aware of the bug that prevents Python from using Popen under WSGI, but I've figured out what *seemed* like a workable (albeit somewhat hack-y) solution: instead of calling Popen with the actual command, I created a .bat and called the bat through Popen with the shell argument set to `True`. This actually works for just about everything **other than** what I needed it to; i.e., calling `start iexplore` worked, `start firefox` worked, even `notepad` and `mspaint`, but the only thing that didn't work, was calling `start chrome`. I've even tried a few command-line arguments, like `start chrome --single-process`, but to no avial.

It's like Windows just hates Chrome. I would greatly appreciate any help, as I've been pulling my hair out over this for the last 48 hours.

**tl;dr: Chrome won't start from a batch script called using `subprocess.Popen`, but everything else will.**

---

**Relevant Technical Stuff**

Python script [excerpt]:

```
import subprocess
command="<path>\\start-browser.bat" # Absolute path to Batch file
subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True)
```

Batch file:

```
start /d "C:\Documents and Settings\<Me>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application" chrome.exe
```

System:

- Windows XP sp3, 32-bit
- Python 2.7
- Apache 2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this in your case, but I know a lot of Chrome's oddities come about because it is installed per user.  Have you tried logging in as Administrator and [installing Chrome for all users](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=118663)?

Comment: **Yes!!** That worked! In fact, I can open it directly with `cmd /c start chrome <url>`. Now, another (less important) problem appears: it doesn't open in the same window as the current one open. I'm assuming its because my subprocesses from Apache are running as System. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Also, it seems that the default browser for the System user is *always* IE, despite the default for my actual user. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: I'd try using the `RUNAS` command to run Chrome as a different user from System http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx

Comment: I'm trying to use `runas` but running into some problems. First, I can't login everytime the server gets a request, and I'm not going to save my user password in a text file. So I created a User named "apache" with limited permissions, but now Chrome is opening with an error.

Comment: There's the `/savecred` option to `runas` but I have no idea how secure that is.

Comment: That worked so that I don't have to log in every time with User `apache`, but it's still giving me the "Aw Snap!" page.