# using wsgi script to call exe

Tags: python, django, exe, wsgi

I'm running apache, Django and wsgi. I also use this other software called **SAS** to do statistical analysis.  Just to give you some context.  My end goal is when a client hits submit on a form written in the django, the appropriate sas script is called *(via a python wsgi script)* which performs calculations on the server, and then redirects the client to the output page.

I have a basic script called `test5.py`.  It looks like this:

```
import os
import subprocess

def application(environ, start_response):

  status = '200 OK'
  output = 'Running External Program!'

  f = open("C:\Documents and Settings\eric\Desktop\out.txt", 'a')
  f.write('hi')
  f.close()

  #os.system(r'start "C:\Program Files\SAS92\SASFoundation\9.2\sas.exe"')
  #subprocess.call([r'C:\Program Files\SAS92\SASFoundation\9.2\sas.exe'])
  #os.startfile(r'C:\Program Files\SAS92\SASFoundation\9.2\sas.exe')
  response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                      ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

  #start_response('301 Redirect', [('Location', 'http://myserver/reports'),])
  start_response(status, response_headers)

  return [output]
```

So what happens is that the `out.txt` file does get created and have `hi` written in the file. That's quite cool. The first 3 commented lines were 3 attempts to have this same script also call `sas.exe` which lives on the server. I'm just trying to get any `.exe` to work right now, so calling paint or wordpad would be fine. Those lines however do not seems to execute in the `wsgi` context. If I just load the Python command line, I can get the `.exes` to execute just fine.  Also the last comment seems to be working properly in the redirecting.  I'm not sure if I need to configure apache to add executables. Please forgive me if I'm using terms incorrectly. I am still quite new to all of this.

Thanks

---

Hi Paulo,

I was trying to look into your last comment.  I am a bit confused as to exactly what i am looking for or how to look for it.  Here is some information that I have gathered.  By the way i am running on windows XP and using Apache 2.2.

My apache is installed for all users as in regedit the variable ServerRoot is under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html).  Also I believe SAS is installed under all users.  I tested this by having my coworker sign in using her login and I still had access.  I’m not sure if that is a sufficient test though.

The log I get when I run the wsgi is the following.  I’m not sure if it matters that the process is empty.

[Mon Aug 20 10:33:17 2012] [info] [client 10.60.8.71] mod_wsgi (pid=5980, process='', application='..com|/test5'): Reloading WSGI script 'C:/Sites/cprm/pyscripts/test5.wsgi'.

Also I tried the .bat trick from the link I posted in the comment i posted earlier to no avail.  I made a simple batch file that just echoes 'hi' and placed it in the same directory where my wsgi scripts live.  I feel like there should be no access problems there, but I may be mistaken.  I also just tried calling a simple python script using subprocess just to test.  Also nothing happened.

Also just to show you, my httpd.conf file looks like such:

AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

WSGIScriptAlias /test1 "C:/sites/cprm/pyscripts/test1.wsgi"
WSGIScriptAlias /test2 "C:/sites/cprm/pyscripts/test2.py"
WSGIScriptAlias /test3 C:/sites/cprm/pyscripts/test3.py
WSGIScriptAlias /test4 "C:/sites/cprm/pyscripts/test4.py"
WSGIScriptAlias /test5 "C:/sites/cprm/pyscripts/test5.wsgi"
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/sites/cprm/wsgi.py"

Is this information helpful or not really?  Also, am i looking for a specific environ variable or something?

Thanks again

Comment: What stat analysis are you doing? proc freq/tabulate/means etc... etc.. ?

Comment: I do credit risk management at a bank.  I wanted a way to front-end a bunch of models i have written in SAS as well as other languages.  Some programs are more computation based, while others will just be used to populate charts/reports.

Answer (score 1):

For web applications that perform background calculations or other tasks, IMHO it is best to queue the tasks for processing instead of calling an external process from a Django view and hang everything until the task completes. This leads to better:

- user experience (request returns instantly - use ajax to signal task status and present the download link once task completes)
- security (background process can run under safer credentials)
- scalability (tasks can be distributed among servers)
- resilience (by default many webservers will send an 'error 500' if your application fails to answer under 30 seconds or so)

For a background daemon processing all entries in the queue, there are several approaches depending on how big you want to scale:

- a cron job
- a daemon using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) (or your watchdog of choice)
- an AMQP module like [django-celery](http://celery.github.com/celery/index.html)

[edit]

The process you start from a WSGI script will run under the same user that is running the webserver. In linux it is generally 'www-data' or 'nobody', in Windows/IIS it is 'IUSR_MachineName' (or authenticated user if using IIS authentication). Check if you can start the program using the same credentials your WSGI is running under.

Comment: This is a great point that I had not considered.  I am looking into django-celery.  I have some tasks which could take 10 hours to run for which that would be perfect.  I also have some queries that take only a few seconds however.  Are my above os.system attempts reasonable in this case?

Also just to help me clarify a few things as i have been researching this.  I can't have it where a client hits submit which triggers javaScript to call a .exe on the server.  Is that correct?

Comment: Also WSGI at a high level accomplishes the same thing that CGI does in that they make dynamic webpage content by being able to call a .py from the browser.  I feel like calling a .exe is not really the main purpose of wsgi.  I guess I'm still unclear as to why my os.system calls do not execute.  Thanks again.

Comment: So it seems like this person has accomplished what i was initially set out to do:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809944/trying-to-start-chrome-from-wsgi-python-admittedly-quick-and-dirty-win-xp-x. Still confused ahhhh.